# Multidimensional sorting of array by value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

So, i have this array(below), and while extracting the values from **query_collumns** with foreach, i want to sort it ascending by  **query_collumn_order**.

I am looking for a simple and elegant solution.
I do not want to restructure, regenerate in any other way the array if possible.

How ?

Thank you all in advance.

```html
Array
(
    [query_id] => 1
    [query_name] => test
    [query_database] => qwe
    [query_main_table] => query
    [query_main_collumn] => query_id
    [query_join] => 
    [query_filter] => 
    [query_orderby] => 
    [query_collumns] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [query_collumn_id] => 1
                    [query_collumn_name] => query_id
                    [query_collumn_order] => 1
                    [query_collumn_width] => 0
                    [query_collumn_visible] => 0
                    [query_collumn_query_id] => 1
                    [query_collumn_user_setting_user_id] => 
                    [query_collumn_user_setting_filter_type] => 
                    [query_collumn_user_setting_filter_value] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [query_collumn_id] => 2
                    [query_collumn_name] => query_name
                    [query_collumn_order] => 4
                    [query_collumn_width] => 1
                    [query_collumn_visible] => 1
                    [query_collumn_query_id] => 1
                    [query_collumn_user_setting_user_id] => 1
                    [query_collumn_user_setting_filter_type] => 
                    [query_collumn_user_setting_filter_value] => 
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [query_collumn_id] => 3
                    [query_collumn_name] => query_database
                    [query_collumn_order] => 3
                    [query_collumn_width] => 0
                    [query_collumn_visible] => 0
                    [query_collumn_query_id] => 1
                    [query_collumn_user_setting_user_id] => 
                    [query_collumn_user_setting_filter_type] => 
                    [query_collumn_user_setting_filter_value] => 
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: The simplest solution would be to use the `ORDER BY <column> ASC` in your query while fetching this data.

Is that not a possibility for you or do you not have database access?

Comment: That is not a possibility, because the query extracts an orderby from a table, and than another orderby form another table is added to the result with left join, basically the second orderby overrites the first one, if it has a value

Comment: turns out, i had to tweak the query, using the ifnull() with ORDER BY

Comment: You do notice that it's spelled *column*, don't you?

Comment: yeah...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the ifnull() with ORDER BY solved my problem. Basically the array generated with the correct order, and post sorting is not required anymore.